# Closing a window using key combinations

Tags: autohotkey

I've mapped the following keys:

```
ALT + Z to be equivalent to ALT + F4
ALT + X to be equivalent to ALT + F + C
```

With the following code:

```
!z::
   Send, !{F4}
!x::
   Send, !fc
```

However, when this code is running and I press **ALT + Z** , the actual keys that are being sent are:

`ALT + F4` and then `ALT + F + C` instead of just `ALT + F4`

What am I doing wrong? How do get the mapping to be correct for ALT+Z?

Comment: Put the commands on the same line with the hotkey definition or add `return`

Comment: thanks so much make that into an answer and ill mark it correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autohotkey hotkey handlers fall through/continue to lines below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813484/autohotkey-hotkey-handlers-fall-through-continue-to-lines-below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `return` statement to tell the script to stop execution

```
!z::
   Send, !{F4}
return

!x::
   Send, !fc
return
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an AutoIt solution that works for me.

```
HotKeySet("!z", "sendKeys")

; Run Notepad just to have something to test with.
Run("notepad.exe", "", @SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func sendKeys()
    Send("!{f4}")
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>sendKeys
```